# Meteor Galaxy "Deploy Failed"

Tags: meteor, deployment, galaxy

I made some recent updates to my Meteor App, most notably updating to Meteor 1.7. Since then Galaxy's deploy fails, errors:

`Talking to Galaxy servers at https://eu-west-1.galaxy.meteor.com
Preparing to deploy your app...

Uploaded app bundle to upgrade kampino.afkl.com.de to version 38.
Galaxy is building the app into a native image.
Building app image...

Deploying app...`

(This message is different than before...)

In the versions tab of Galaxy it says: **Deploy Failed**

Any idea?

When I checkout the older version everything works normal again.

I suppose it is about Meteor 1.7 but didn't find any issue or question on it.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone has the same problem:
It seems like in the new Galaxy Deployment some special characters my password was containing don't go anymore. Error log:

**Error: Password contains an illegal unescaped character**